# Bayesian prior estimation linear models

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models

I am trying to make this mixed linear model using BUGS Nimble. I am confused about how to put the categorical variable z in the code, as when I try gamma* z , it gives me ops.factor error, but this is how it is in the question.
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LxIQ.png)

My R code is follows

```
writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")
library(nimble)
library(igraph)
library(coda)
library(R6)


y <-c(19.9,27.3,21.0,3.7,48.4,66.4,13.1,38.6,22.7,17.4,40.7,47.0,53.7,61.9,80.8,11.4,16.2,8.6,32.6,60.4)
z <-factor(c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1))
x <-c(3,6,4,1,9,15,1,7,6,2,9,12,14,17,18,3,5,2,8,12)
plot(x, y,col=c(rep("red",2),rep("blue",2)),
     xlim =c(0, 25),ylim=c(0,90))
summary(fm<-lm(y~z-1+x))
model.matrix(~z+x)
for(i in 1 : 20) 
for(j in 1:2)
  phi[j,i] <- gamma*(z[i])
  
  y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i] ,tau) mu[i] <-phi[j,i]+ beta*(x[i])+alpha


#   Prior specification:
alpha ~ dnorm(0,0.00001)

beta ~dnorm(0,0.00001)

gamma~dnorm(0,0.00001)

tau~dgamma(0.001,0.001) 
sigma2 <- 1 / tau

#   Input   initial  parameter  values:
list(alpha  =  0,    beta=  0, gamma=0,  tau=  1)
```

Comment: You write that first line everytime you run this script?

Comment: No, I just added it here thinking maybe I am missing something. That line is from my instructors code. I am not sure what it does. I am new to R.